# User specific Serializers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating Serializers in my DRF and so far it's working good the problem is that it is showing data of all the users

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Quiz


class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('foo', 'bar')
```

How do I make my Serializers User Specific such that it only returns the data of the user who is using the app?

**Views.py**

```
class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = TodoSerializer
  queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User specific filtering has nothing to do with serializers. Serializers are used to convert complex python objects to/from native python datatypes that can be rendered in JSON/XML etc. It is convenient to do your filtering in your view. Here is an example by using mixins:

```py
# views.py
from .models import Quiz
from .serializers import TodoSerializer
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TodoListViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    queryset = models.Quiz.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # filter your todos here
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=request.user)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I have updated the question with my Views.py. Can I just add your `def list..` to it ?

Comment: Also I am getting an error `NameError: name 'mixins' is not defined`

Comment: You can add ```list``` to your view. And you need to import mixins, see my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but how can I use the code ? and do I need to import response too? beacuse I am getting `name 'Response' is not defined`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just put that in ```views.py``` and do not touch anything else. You are getting errors because aof the missing imports.